# Is Fermat's Factorization Method used in any practical application?

Tags: factoring

Is there any use for Fermat's Factorization Method in the world of cryptography? I see that several algorithms are based on it, such as the quadratic sieve and general number field sieve. I understand that Fermat's can be very fast if the factors are close to the square root. Generally RSA moduli have factors that are far enough apart to be resistant to Fermat's.

Are there any real-world examples of when Fermat's Method would be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a recent instance (March 14th 2022) of the breaking of RSA public keys which were generated carelessly (full report [here](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/03/researcher-uses-600-year-old-algorithm-to-crack-crypto-keys-found-in-the-wild/)). Apparently that version of the software is no longer used.

> Cryptographic keys generated with older software now owned by technology company Rambus are weak enough to be broken instantly using commodity hardware, a researcher reported on Monday. This revelation is part of an investigation that also uncovered a handful of weak keys in the wild.

> the vulnerable SafeZone library doesn't sufficiently randomize the two prime numbers it used to generate RSA keys. (These keys can be used to secure Web traffic, shells, and other online connections.) Instead, after the SafeZone tool selects one prime number, it chooses a prime in close proximity as the second one needed to form the key.

**Edit:** Here are some more links
Fermat attack site: https://fermatattack.secvuln.info/

Code: https://github.com/badkeys/badkeys

Script which checks this and other vulnerabilities: https://badkeys.info/

Comment: Did they release a code? Do you know about it?