# What kind of special numbers are not suitable as RSA keys?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, factoring

I have [read](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap4.pdf) that some integers are not appropriate to be chosen as the modulus in an RSA cryptosystem. Some of these numbers are those that, given a modulus $n=pq$, then $p-1$ or $q-1$ do not have large factors. This is due to the fact that there are factorization algorithms that allow this type of modulus to be factored efficiently.

My question is, what other types of integers are not suitable to be used as a modulus and why?

--

Edit:

**Other kind of numbers not suitable as RSA modulus:**

- p+1 and q+1 without big factors: [kelalaka](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/18298/kelalaka) highlights the use of the [Williams p+1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59788/18298) algorithm.
- p and q with close values: [kelalaka](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/18298/kelalaka) highlights the use of [Fermat's factorization method](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/102252/is-fermats-factorization-method-used-in-any-practical-application).

Comment: Probably the Q duplicates this [Is it reasonable to assure that p-1 and q-1 aren't smooth?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1151/18298) and this [Williams' p+1 in tandem with Pollard's p−1?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59788/18298) and this [Finding strong primes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22554/18298) and finally this [Generation of strong primes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20548/18298)

Comment: It is edited in 2000, and it is old. Check the links that I've provided to you to see.

Comment: Thanks @kelalaka, it seems that due to Williams p+1 we also have to worry about large factors at p+1 and q+1, which is very interesting. But I think my question remains open. What other kinds of numbers do we have to worry about?

Comment: [close primes due to Fermat's factoring](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/102252/is-fermats-factorization-method-used-in-any-practical-application)

Comment: Thans again kelalaka, i've edited the question. Let's see if anyone knows of other cases.

Comment: @kelalaka: yes the HAC is old, but it's still excellent for what it covers, and can't be construed as stating that strong primes matter in RSA. On the contrary, section 4.4.2 states _"it is now believed that strong primes offer little protection beyond that offered by random primes"_.

Comment: @fgrieu I don't agree that, some parts needs to be updated. I wish they updated to be content or released the $\LaTeX$ code on github etc. so that it is still as reliable as 15 years ago.

Comment: Of cource, if you want to read you can read [20 years of RSA](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/abstracts/RSAattack-survey.html) paper from Dan Boneh.